# Labelling lists and equations at odds

Tags: numbering

I have a section where I describe lists with:

`\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic*{enumi}.}`

and equations with:

`\renewcommand{\theequation}{\labelenumi-\arabic{equation}}`

So of course, my equation numbering ends up looking like:

1.-1

But I would prefer to both label my lists 1., 2., and 3. and my equations 1-1, 1-2, & 1-3.  Is there a way to do this?

mwe:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\textbf{PROBLEMS}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic*{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\labelenumi-\arabic{equation}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\setcounter{equation}{0}
%%1%%
\item Consider:

\begin{equation}\label{eq: 5.1.1}
a \times b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq: 5.1.2}
a = \sqrt{bc}
\end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
%%2%%
\item  Another problem.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\labelenumi-\arabic{equation}}
```

you can use

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{enumi}-\arabic{equation}}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\textbf{PROBLEMS}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{enumi}-\arabic{equation}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\setcounter{equation}{0}
%%1%%
\item Consider:

\begin{equation}\label{eq: 5.1.1}
a \times b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq: 5.1.2}
a = \sqrt{bc}
\end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
%%2%%
\item  Another problem.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should use `amsmath`, first of all. Then you can exploit `enumitem`'s features:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{enumeq}
 {\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{enumi}-\arabic{equation}}%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,before=\changeitem]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
  \let\ORIitem\item
  \renewcommand\item{%
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
    \ORIitem
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\textbf{PROBLEMS}

\begin{enumeq}
\item Consider:
\begin{gather}
a \times b = c
\label{eq: 5.1.1}
\\
a = \sqrt{bc}
\label{eq: 5.1.2}
\end{gather}

\item  Another problem
\begin{equation}
 a=b
\end{equation}
\end{enumeq}

Here are the references: \eqref{eq: 5.1.1} and \eqref{eq: 5.1.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]